# Creating folders in Cygwin results in incorrectly ordered permissions, failure to open files

Tags: windows, security, permissions, cygwin, file-permissions

This is something recent with my Cygwin on Win 10. If I do "mkdir folder", then in Windows, checking folder properties and selecting the Security tab gives the popup: The permissions on folder are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some entries to be ineffective.
If I then create a file in that folder from Windows, in order to open that file, I have to first remove one of the permissions entries under Properties>Security>Advanced for that file. That entry indicates "deny special access for the owner of the file".
What is causing incorrect ordering of permissions and also what I believe is the wrong permissions to be assigned to newly-created folder in Cygwin?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082542/1088084

Answer (score 2):

Source: [Forcing Cygwin to create sane permissions on Windows](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/forcing-cygwin-to-create-sane-permissions-on-windows)

Adding the noacl option to this file worked for me on Windows 10 Home with Cygwin x64:

```
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 3.1.6(0.340/5/3) 2020-07-09 08:20 x86_64 Cygwin
```

You may need to find where your Cygwin folder is located.

File:

```
C:\cygwin64\etc\fstab
```

Contents:

```
# /etc/fstab
#
#    This file is read once by the first process in a Cygwin process tree.
#    To pick up changes, restart all Cygwin processes.  For a description
#    see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

# This is default anyway:
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,noacl,posix=0,user 0 0
```

After changing the fstab file I had to reboot my PC.

Also, when I used rsync I passed these arguments:

```
time rsync -avh --delete --progress --chmod=ugo=rwX /cygdrive/s/source/ /cygdrive/d/destination/
```