# Files created by executable in cygwin have incorrect permissions to 000

Tags: cygwin

I already tried the solution [cygwin sets file permission to 000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828037/cygwin-sets-file-permission-to-000).  It doesn't work.  Actually, my version of cygwin `1.5.25(0.156/4/2)` doesn't even have file /etc/fstab...

So, my problem is I have an executable that creates binary files.  Those generated files have permission 000.  I did the same test by calling the same executable on windows, and then permission are correct.  See :

*Files created on windows side:*

```
$ ls -ls pct-win/
total 2135
   0 -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users       0 Jan 22 16:56 autopron*
   1 -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users     281 Jan 22 16:56 grammar*
2132 -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 2179493 Jan 22 16:56 lexicon*
   1 -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users      79 Jan 22 16:56 package*
   1 -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users     223 Jan 22 16:56 semantic*
```

*Files created on cygwin side*

```
$ ls -ls pct
total 2135
   0 ----------+ 1 pboily Domain Users       0 Jan 23 11:07 autopron
   1 ----------+ 1 pboily Domain Users     281 Jan 23 11:07 grammar
2132 ----------+ 1 pboily Domain Users 2179493 Jan 23 11:07 lexicon
   1 ----------+ 1 pboily Domain Users      79 Jan 23 11:07 package
   1 ----------+ 1 pboily Domain Users     223 Jan 23 11:07 semantic
```

Ah, and one last thing, if I create a file with `touch`, permissions look like this :

`-rw-r--r-- 1 pboily Domain Users 0 Jan 23 11:18 toto.txt`

Comment: So, why are you using an obsolete version of Cygwin?

Comment: @varro Because I unfortunately have to bring a fix on a really old software that we are still selling.  Upgrading our environment will cost more.  This project use visual studio 2003.  Oh yeah, really, I have a loooooooooooot of fun.

Comment: how you created the files, what are the permissions of the directory and what is the value shows by `umask`  ?